# c# byte[] leftshift for an output reduction

Tags: c#

I'm trying to left shift bits to create a type of "reduction"

example:

byte[] key =>  00000001 00000001 00000000 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000001 00000001

the wanted output => 11010011

I'm trying

```
for (int i = key.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--){

  key[i] = (byte)((key[i] << 7) & ((i == 0) ? 0 : key[i - 1] >> 0));

}
```

Comment: byte[] input = { 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1 };
            byte output = (byte)input.Select((x, i) => x << (7 - i)).Sum();

Comment: ty for ur replay, i need a byte[] output, i have this code but is very slow for a large file.
`
byte[] key => 00000001 00000001 00000000 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000001 00000001

byte[] keyByte = new byte[keysize + 1];
            BitArray bitatkx = new BitArray(keyByte);
            int i = 0;
            foreach (byte n in key)
            {
                bitatkx.Set(i, Convert.ToBoolean(n));
                bitatkx.CopyTo(keyByte, 0);
                i++;
            }`@jdweng

Comment: Assuming the input is an array of bytes :             byte[] input = { 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }; 
            byte[] output = input.Select((x,i) => new { x = x, i = i}).GroupBy(x => x.i/ 8)
                .Select(x => (byte)x.Select((y, i) => y.x << (7 - i)).Sum()).ToArray();

Answer (score 0):

This work, ty @jdweng

```
byte[] input = { 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }; 
byte[] output = input.Select((x,i) => new { x = x, i = i}).GroupBy(x => x.i/ 8) .Select(x => (byte)x.Select((y, i) => y.x << (7 - i)).Sum()).ToArray();
```